# MIN and MAX in case expression

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, case

I want to get MIN or Max date base on condition`(s.REQUIRED_DATE >= trunc(SYSDATE-1))`.

Below is my query.

It gives me error `ORA-00937: not a single-group group function`

```
SELECT 
case when s.REQUIRED_DATE >= trunc(SYSDATE-1) then
    MIN(required_date)
else
    MAX(required_date)
end required_date
FROM anytable s
WHERE     s.abc = 'hhj';
```

How can I achieve this?

> Query must return 17-AUG-2020 for 'hhj' and 15-AUG-2020 for 'bbj'

```
id    abc    required_date
1     hhj    14-Aug-2020
2     hhj    17-AUG-2020
3     hhj    19-AUG-2020
3     bbj    15-AUG-2020
4     bbj    12-AUG-2020
```

I can adopt any other approach also if required.
Please suggest

Comment: yes you need `group by REQUIRED_DATE` since that's not aggregated.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan i already tried that but it gives me 3 records

Comment: can you share sample input and desired output? ( and how you got three records as result )

Comment: From my point of view, what you trying to do is kind of wrong. It appears that - for each `s.abc` column value - table contains more than a single row. But, in all those rows, `s.required_date` can be larger, smaller or equal to `trunc(sysdate - 1)` which means that such a query won't return a single value. If, on the other hand, there's only one row for each `s.abc` value, then using MIN or MAX on that "single" `required_date` is useless as MIN = MAX = `required_date` itself. Sample data would certainly help.

Comment: @Littlefoot  added sample data and required output

Comment: TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) = (currently) 16-AUG-2020. Why should HHJ have 17-AUG-2020 as a result, and not 19-AUG-2020? What rules lead from input to desired result? Please, could you explain it for both HHJ and BBJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, for a particular `abc` you want to get:

- the `required_date` nearest to and past the date yesterday if there's a `required_date` past the date yesterday, or
- get the latest `required_date` if they don't pass the date yesterday.

If so, this query may be what you wanted:

```
select
  case when max(required_date)>=trunc(sysdate-1) then
    min(case when required_date>=trunc(sysdate-1) then required_date end)
    else max(required_date)
  end required_date
from anytable s
where s.abc='hhj';
```

Comment: Bulls eye..u got it .Exactly what i wanted.Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use Aggregate function on whole case statement and for this you have to use two case statements.

```
SELECT 
MIN(case when s.ENTRY_DATE >= trunc(SYSDATE-1) then
    ENTRY_DATE
end) MIN_required_date,
MAX(case when s.ENTRY_DATE < trunc(SYSDATE-1) then
    ENTRY_DATE
end) MAX_required_date
FROM DATE_TEST s
```

Comment: Those are case _expressions_, they return a value.

Comment: I mean these are _expressions_, not _statements_. (Case _statements_ are used in a stored procedure for conditional execution of code.)